# How to make an animation that displaying a UIImageView gradually?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have an `UIImageView` object with the frame, say, x = 0, y = 100, width = 320, height = 200.

Now I want to make an animation such that this image can be shown gradually, meaning that the height of the showing part is growing from 0 to 200 gradually.

I tried to realize this by resizing the image frame, but if I do so, the image itself will be scaled accordingly, which is not what I want.

I also tried to set "Mode" of the `UIImageView` to "Top" rather than "Scale to Fit". But because I'm doing this in the XCode inspector, the image loaded is, for example, `img@2x.png`, so if I choose "Top", the image will be 2 times bigger.

By the way, I also have tried to use a covering rectangle and move it. But this method will together cover other background images, so does not work.

Could anyone help?

Comment: How is the interface builder related to the fact that the image will be 2 times larger? What is your presented image size?

Comment: @StatusReport, my image is 640 * 200 in pixels, so when displaying in Retina, it would be 320 * 100. But If I cancel "Scale to Fit" in the interface builder, it will be 640 * 200 at the very beginning.

Comment: In this case, to avoid upsampling artifacts you'll really want an 1280 * 400 pixels image instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the mask property of CALayer that backs the imageView (e.g. `imgView.layer.mask`). You should be able to animate that.

Answer (score 0):

First give height of your `Imageview` is **0**.

And Take a `NSTimer` *(here with method name `doAnimation`)* and give its `TimeInterVal` is **1** Second.

Here `doAnimation` method fire after **1** second. Write code of `doAnimation` method.

```
-(void)doAnimation
{
    //// here you can give animation duration as you want. 

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.35 animations:^{
         self.myImageView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 100, 320,200);

  }];
}
```

**This code might help you in your case:**

Comment: I'm not quite clear your answer, but now I find FelixLam's method is good, anyway, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add it like this:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,0)];
view.clipsToBounds = YES;
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake:(0,0,320,200)];
imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"your image"];
[view addSubview:imgView];
[imgView release];
[self.view addSubview:view];
```

Now you do this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5];
[view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,200)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

This is tested!

Answer (score 0):

can use something like this

```
image.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 0.01);
[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
    // animate it to the identity transform (100% scale)
    image.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
} completion:^(BOOL finished){
    // if you want to do something once the animation finishes, put it here
}];
```